# Python: How to access a list of urls through a list of proxies?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Right now I have this code tenatively:

```
import json
import urllib2  

with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    for line in proxies:
        proxy = json.loads(line)
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for line in urls:
        url = line.rstrip()
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        print data
```

my proxies.txt file is as follows:

```
{"https": "https://94.142.27.4:3128"}
{"http": "http://118.97.95.174:8080"}
{"http": "http://66.62.236.15:8080"}
```

and my urls.txt file is as follows:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.reddit.com
```

It seems that it is installing all proxies and then processing each url in the list with all of the proxies installed. What I really want though, is for it to access each url through each proxy individually. So

1. access url1 through proxy 1
2. access url2 through proxy 1
3. access url3 through proxy 1
4. access url1 through proxy 2
5. access url2 through proxy 2
6. access url3 through proxy 2
7. access url1 through proxy 3
8. access url2 through proxy 3
9. access url3 through proxy 3

is there a way to do this? Is it already doing this? Am I misunderstanding what a proxy really is? Am I misunderstanding what install_opener really does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but...

Since you want try all URL through all proxies, you could use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to easily build all the combinations:

```
import itertools

with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    with open('urls.txt') as urls:
        for (proxie, url) in itertools.product(proxies, urls):
            print "access", url.rstrip(), "using", proxie.rstrip()
```

Of course, instead of the `print` you will have to insert your actual code.

---

That said, the only *real* problem with your original code is probably the indentation. You want *nested* loops. So that how you should have written it:

```
with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    for line in proxies:
        proxy = json.loads(line)
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

        with open('urls.txt') as urls:
            for line in urls:
                url = line.rstrip()
                data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
                print data
```